# where do the probability and statistics questions go? (math.se or stats.se)

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

hi,

So I apologize if this question was covered somewhere, or its a little ignorant but I did search for it.

Where do questions on the following topics go :

- Poisson's, Norma, Binomial Distributions
- Probability Density Functions(They involve integration)
- Sampling, Hypothesis testing etc.

Are they valid for math.se or do they to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or can I post them on either? (I only see a `distributions`tag on stats.SE besides a `c++`tag.

Thanks.

Gideon

Comment: If you read the stat.stackexchange FAQ, it says pretty clearly all the above questions are okay.   I don't think such questions would be off-topic here.  But you should probably avoid posting your questions on both forums.  Pick whichever you think is more appropriate given the exact context of your question.